# Some files are 404 'ing in magento 2

Tags: magento2, 404

Some files seem to be missing and so displays as 404. I've not deleted these files as I don't even know where they sit.

[image: Error 404]

Anyone know how to fix this?

I've tried reindexing and deploying static content.

Comment: have you resolve? if yes please post solution and close

Answer (score 1):

Please try enable Sign Static Files in System Configuration:
**System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Static Files Settings -> Sign Static Files**

and redeploy static content

Comment: Tried the above but still no change. Any other ideas?